# Understanding a Haskell type from an old exam

Tags: haskell

I am studying for a Haskell exam and I'm a bit stuck on this question:
[image]

My first thought was to write something like this

```
paste :: Region -> Image a -> Image a -> Image a
paste (Image bol) img1 img2 = if bol
                              then -- do the pasting
                              else -- well do nothing
```

But I don't know how to do the pasting. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: the pasting is just copying the values from one list to another, what should be, if the region you are checking is in the image1 region take that values, otherwise thake image1 values

Comment: I don't get what that `paste` do. Why does it accept `Image Bool` instead of `Bool`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While this is little use when you're actually sitting in an exam, here's the “teach a man to trawl-fish” answer: *start out without defining any result at all, and let the compiler* (must be GHC≥7.8) *comment on it*. Note that the stub is wrong: if `Image` is just a `type`-def, you don't need the value constructor `Image` to pattern match on it.

```
newtype Image a = Image (Position -> a)
    -- it should be `newtype` instead of `type`, else there
    -- won't be an explicit `Image` value constructor
type Position = (Float, Float)
type Region = Image Bool

paste :: Region -> Image a -> Image a -> Image a
paste (Image bol) img1 img2 = _
```

GHC will come back with

```
/tmp/wtmpf-file6644.hs:8:31:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: Image a
    Where: ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for
                 paste :: Region -> Image a -> Image a -> Image a
    ...
```

Ok, that's hardly surprising: we already know that the result should be an image. Now, there's only one contructor for `Image`, namely `Image`, so we know for sure we need that to construct such an image. Still don't know anything about the *inner implementation*:

```
paste (Image bol) img1 img2 = Image _
```

gives

```
/tmp/wtmpf-file6644.hs:8:37:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: Position -> a
    Where: ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for
                 paste :: Region -> Image a -> Image a -> Image a
               at /tmp/wtmpf-file6644.hs:7:10
```

Aha, so there's an extra function argument lurking hidden in the `Image`! Let's pattern match on that, too:

```
paste (Image bol) img1 img2 = Image $ \pos -> _

/tmp/wtmpf-file6644.hs:8:47:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: a
    ...
```

Ok, `a` is completely opaque, so now we know for sure there's *nothing we can do without further information*. Fortunately, we do have further information, in form of the arguments. As GHC will inform you:

```
    ...
    Relevant bindings include
      pos :: Position (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file6644.hs:8:40)
      img2 :: Image a (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file6644.hs:8:24)
      img1 :: Image a (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file6644.hs:8:19)
      bol :: Position -> Bool (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file6644.hs:8:14)
```

There's not *much* we can do with that... which is good, because this makes it obvious what *should* be done: we can feed `pos` as an argument to `bol`. The result has then type `Bool` (unlike `bol` itself), so that is now a good candidate for an `if` switch.

```
paste (Image bol) img1 img2 = Image $ \pos -> if bol pos
         then _
         else _
```

...

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: a
      ...
```

seen that before, so again we need more information. Let's look back at those arguments: `Image a` can still be pattern matched

```
paste (Image bol) (Image img1) (Image img2)
  = Image $ \pos -> if bol pos
         then _
         else _
```

Now it says:

```
    Relevant bindings include
      pos :: Position (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file6644.hs:9:14)
      img2 :: Position -> a (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file6644.hs:8:39)
      img1 :: Position -> a (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file6644.hs:8:26)
      bol :: Position -> Bool (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file6644.hs:8:14)
```

Aha, so `img1` and `img2` can yield an `a` value as we need, we just need them to feed a `Position` first. Well, we still have `pos`, so it's obvious what to do:

```
paste (Image bol) (Image img1) (Image img2)
  = Image $ \pos -> if bol pos
         then img1 pos
         else img2 pos
```

...or with the two images swapped (think about that yourself). But there aren't really any other definitions you can write using only the given information (and *all* of it!), so this typed-hole procedure is a pretty foolproof way of implementing a function.

Comment: Nice explanation! I think I got it. Thank you for showing the procedure too. It was the pattern matching I didn't get at first but now I got it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All right.  You’ve got your screen coordinates represented by a [0,1]×[0,1] rectangle.  A region is a boolean function over that rectangle, which returns true if and only if a coordinate is in that region.  Then you have two images, `img1` and `img2`, which are mappings from coordinates to pixels (or in theory to something else).

You want to return a new image, which is equal to `img1` for coordinates within `reg` or `img2` for coordinates outside `reg`.  Images are mappings from coordinates to pixels, so you are really returning a function.

The type is `Region -> Image a -> Image a -> Image a`, but remember that `Image a` is `Position -> a`, and `Region` is `Image Bool`, so this is really `(Position -> Bool) -> (Position -> a) -> (Position -> a ) -> Position -> a`.  We’re going to need that final `Position` parameter before the `-> a` and give it as an argument to the three function parameters.

Therefore,

```
paste :: Region -> Image a -> Image a -> Image a
-- Is really: (Position->Bool) -> (Position->a) -> (Position->a) -> Position -> a
paste reg overlay bg coords | reg coords == True = overlay coords
                            | otherwise          = bg coords
```

A longer version with a test case:

```
module Image where

type Image a = Position -> a
type Position = (Float, Float) -- [0,1]×[0,1]

data Color = RGB Int Int Int -- Pixels have values in [0,255]×[0,255]×[0,255].
  deriving Show
-- Not efficient for real-world use, but will do for now.

type Region = Image Bool
type ColorImage = Image Color

paste :: Region -> Image a -> Image a -> Image a
-- Is really: (Position->Bool) -> (Position->a) -> (Position->a) -> Position -> a
paste reg overlay bg coords | reg coords == True = overlay coords
                            | otherwise          = bg coords

allRed :: ColorImage
allRed _ = RGB 255 0 0

allWhite :: ColorImage
allWhite _ = RGB 255 255 255

unitCircle :: Region
unitCircle (x,y) = sqrt (x'*x' + y'*y') <= 0.5
  where x' = x - 0.5
        y' = y - 0.5

redCircleOnWhite :: ColorImage
redCircleOnWhite = paste unitCircle allRed allWhite
```

You can test `redCircleOnWhite` in the REPL.

Comment: How do you match `Image Bool` with `True` or `False`?

Comment: Noticed that myself.  Fixed now.

Comment: Okay, that seems to work.  Hope the explanation is clear.

Comment: I don't get what coords is in your function. Apart from that I appreciate your test example.

Comment: In that example `coords` is the fourth parameter of a function whose parameters are `Region`, `Image a`, `Image a` and `Position`.  So it’s a `Position`, which is defined as `(Float, Float)`.  So, try it with `redCircleOnWhite (0.5, 0.5)` and `redCircleOnWhite (1.0, 1,0)`.  (I changed the definition of `unitCircle` so it is now an actual circle, not a quarter-circle.)

Comment: Ah! Now I get it. Thanks

Comment: Although `unitCircle` is now no longer a *unit* circle.

Comment: You can avoid `== True` by simply omitting it.

Comment: @chi True! (I could have avoided saying that as well.) In this case, I guessed it made the example slightly clearer. By all means omit it if you prefer!