# What is the typed hole exploration development style?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

While doing the CIS194 (Spring of 2013) homework 10, I got stuck with `Applicative` instance of a `Parser` type. I seek help from Google, an I came across with this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskellquestions/comments/3kgoxf/cis_194_hw_10/). The user ephrion gave an answer, which was also an example of typed hole exploration method, which I didn't quite understand. In the comments section of his answer he also said this:

> It's extremely useful and one of the things that makes Haskell development so nice.

So question is, what this method  is exactly, and are there some explicit order of steps in this method?

I still consider myself as a beginner when it comes to Haskell, and by googling about the subject I didn't find a very clear explanation how this kind of development style could be used.

Comment: I demonstrated it in a couple of StackOverflow answers, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44238966/745903

Comment: When you have a rough idea about what the code should look like, but you are unsure about what to write in some spot, you can simply write a hole `_` as a placeholder. Then, GHC will tell you what type that hole must have to make everything type check. Usually, you replace the hole with more code, possibly having more holes inside so to explore more, until you can write the full code without holes.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's a really good and clear example. Thank you!

Comment: You can also name the holes, which is useful if there are several. `_thishole`, `_thathole`

Comment: I also use type holes combination with `ScopedTypeVariables` to find out what type a certain expression has, e.g. `thing :: _ <- fmap . traverse .... somethingverycomplicated`

Comment: @dfeuer That is good to know!

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Nice tip!

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, almost every time I start writing a Haskell module without `ScopedTypeVariables` I end up adding it at some point. I've trained myself to just start with it enabled.

Comment: @severij, please do accept the response that best answers your question. :)

Comment: @BjarturThorlacius I understood the method finally by reading the Stack Overflow answer leftaroundabout provided, but since your answer is the only one, I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost anywhere on the right hand side of an assignment in Haskell, you can write an underscore (optionally followed by other characters) instead of a value (constant or function). Instead of compiling, GHC will then tell you which type of value you might want to replace the underscore with, and list which identifiers in scope are of that type.

Matthías Páll Gissurarson is expanding the list of hints from GHC to include compound expressions.